# RabbitMQ several consumers in the same process

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a .NET project that needs to read messaged from a given Queue. 
I have several producers writing the same type of message into the queue.
I want my consumer app to have several threads reading messages and handling them so that the load will not be on a single thread.

Any ideas or sample code on how to achieve this?
Again, Note:
Each message should be processed once and not several times. The work should be balanced between the worker threads

Comment: Have one cosumer that hands of each message to a worker thread.

Comment: have some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a bit of plumbing to get that done.

I have an open-source service bus called [Shuttle.Esb](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/) and there are many other service bus options available that you may wish to consider.

But if you do not want to go that route you could still have a look at some of the code and implementations to get some ideas.  I have a [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb.RabbitMQ) implementation that may be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at masstransit project : http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html

It has configurations like prefetch count and concurrency limit. It brings you to consume messages paralelly.

Also it is very simple to setup:

```
IBusControl busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host(new Uri(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQUri),
        hst =>
        {
            hst.Username(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQUserName);
            hst.Password(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQPassword);
        });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host,
        RabbitMQConstants.YourQueueName,
        endPointConfigurator => { 
            endPointConfigurator.Consumer<SomeConsumer>();
            endPointConfigurator.UseConcurrencyLimit(4);
        });
});

busControl.Start();

public class SomeConsumer :
    IConsumer<YourMessageClass>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<YourMessageClass> context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message consumed: {context.Message.YourValue}");

    }
}
```